# React Material UI Column width property does not expand

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

So I am experimenting with React Material UI Tables. I am trying to set auto with property for the columns but it does not expand as expected. Here I wanted the columns to be fully extended and not wrapped.

I tried to add property in the `<Table size="small" style={{ width: auto}}>` but it does not respond. Also, I am afraid it would be a bad practice if I set value by pixel value here?

Is there a better way to set individual columns by percentage or some other flexible types? or table as a whole?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a simple sample of your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: My code is something similar to the following example but with larger name of the column plus more additional columns so that it expands with horizontal scroll https://codesandbox.io/s/suq42?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set  `white-space: "nowrap"` for `th`. Here's the changes based on your code:

```
const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      whiteSpace: "nowrap"
    },
    head: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
      color: theme.palette.common.white
    },
    body: {
      fontSize: 14
    }
  })
)(TableCell);
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]